# Neo4J - Query graph in temporary state

Tags: neo4j, transactions

I have a graph in which I would like to examine the effects of removing/adding nodes but not persist these changes and am wondering if this is possible?

For example, adding a node to the graph, running some aggregate functions to see how this would impact but not change the underlying data.

Is it possible to change the graph in a transaction, query the changed graph then rollback to the original state? Or would I potentially have to either copy the graph or keep a log of changes and revert manually?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j has transaction handling which allows you to make modifications and then commit the results, or roll them back. But all of your operations need to  be done in the transaction context.

This is easiest to do in either a java stored procedure or from any client such as C#.

How do you query the graph?